# Mathematical induction for proving boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, induction

So consider a sequence {$x_n$}, where $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 2$ and $x_n = \frac{1}{2} (x_{n-2} + x_{n-1})$. Now I would like to show that $1 \le x_n \le 2$ by induction. I first show that $x_3 = \frac{3}{2}$ which is indeed inside the range. Now for $k \ge 3, k \in \mathbb{N}$, assume $1 \le x_k \le 2$, then consider $x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} (x_{k-1} + x_{k})$. Since I have already assumed $x_k$ is inside the range, does that mean $x_{k-1}$ is automatically included in the range too?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  have you considered using strong (complete) induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't imply that.

I think that the natural way to go is to use strong induction here. You have $x_1,x_2\in[1,2]$. Now, take $k\in\Bbb N$ and assume that $j\leqslant k\implies a_j\in[1,2]$. Then $a_{k+1}=\frac{a_k+a_{k-1}}2$ and, since both $a_k$ and $a_{k-1}$ belong to $[1,2]$, then so does $a_{k+1}$.