# prove by induction the following statement

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I want to test the following using mathematical induction.

If $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$ and $x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_{n+1})$ prove that $1 \leq x_n \leq 2$ for all $n$ natural

My idea was to do induction on n, for this I considered the following

basic step

Let $n=1$, then $x_{1+2}=x_3=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)=\frac{1}{2}(2+1)=\frac{1}{2}(3)=\frac{3}{2}$, and clearly the equality is verified.

Now, for the inductive step, we can consider as hypothesis of induction that $1 \leq x_n \leq 2$ with $x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_{n+1})$, $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$

Thus, let $x_{(n+1)+2}=x_{n+3}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}+x_{n+2})=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}( x_n + x_{n+1}))$

Now, it is not very clear to me how to accommodate the inequality to conclude the demonstration, any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematical induction for proving boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034308/mathematical-induction-for-proving-boundedness). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x_%7Bn%2B2%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D(x_n%2Bx_%7Bn%2B1%7D)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%241%20%5Cleq%20x_n%20%5Cleq%202%24&p=1).

Comment: FYI,  there are also many related questions here to show this recurrence relation is convergent, e.g., [$a_n = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$](/q/1330605), [Proof of convergence of a recursive sequence](/q/1194510) and (for more general initial conditions) [recursive sequence](/q/378835).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use strong induction to establish that $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ are in $[1,2]$ and then just bound
$$
x_{n+2} = \frac{x_n+x_{n+1}}{2},
$$
which is their average...

Answer (score 1):

It is the average of the two preceding numbers, and avg is between them. So after 2 more iterations you get numbers between 1 and 2, and so avg will be between them and between 1 and 2. And so on and so forth.